# Play parse video in android videoview

Tags: java, android, eclipse, parse-platform, android-videoview

I have stored a video as a file in Parse.com, it's name in Parse is "eventvideo.mp4". I am trying to retrieve this file and play it in a videoview. However, when I run the application I get the dialog message, "Can't play this video. Could someone please help? This is what I have tried..

```
final ParseFile file = post.getFile();
            if (file.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(".jpg"))
            {               
                holder.event.setParseFile(file);
            } else {
                holder.event.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.videvent.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                Uri myUr = Uri.parse(file.toString());
                  mc.setAnchorView(holder.videvent);
                  mc.setMediaPlayer(holder.videvent);       
                holder.videvent.setVideoURI(myUr);
                holder.videvent.requestFocus();
                holder.videvent.start();
            }
```

Comment: I think it should be `file.getUrl()` instead of `file.toString()`.

Comment: @Titus  thanks! that worked perfectly